# Cannot connect to EC2 instance using port other than 22 or ping

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have my EC2 instance security group inbound rule to accept my ip as follows:
[image]

Outbound rule as follows:
[image]

I can connect to my instance using ssh and also ping my instance from my local machine without any issues.

When I have a server running on my EC2 instance on http protocol in port 9999 I am unable to access this site.

`netstat -peanut` gives me the following output on the server:
[image]

I am not sure why I am not able to access the http page locally? Should anything change in my inbound rule? I tested this on Amazon linux and ubuntu images. Nothing works.

Comment: If you SSH into the instance and run `curl localhost:9999`, does it return anything?

Comment: I think your application expects IPv6 traffic, meanwhile you are trying to connect to it using IPv4. AWS handles IPv4 and IPv6 differently. Try allowing inbound and outbound traffic for IPv6.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it does return a page

Comment: Okay, from the instance again try `curl <local IP>:9999` and if that works, try `curl <public IP>:9999`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I don't think the server is ipv6. I tried with a python server which is ipv4, still I couldn't access port 8000 of the python server

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I can curl using the private ip but cannot using the public ip inside the instance. Does that mean anything?

Comment: It means that the traffic is not _entering_ the instance. That's probably because the Inbound rule on the security group is only allowing inbound access from the `54.240.197.244/28` CIDR range. If you _temporarily_ change that setting to `0.0.0.0/0`, does it work from the instance and does it work from your own computer? Also, have you changed the NACLs from their default "Allow All" settings?

Comment: I changed the rule to include instance ip and then I can curl from the instance. I added my ip also to the inbound rule but I cannot curl from my machine. I didn't change the NACLs and I cannot make the instance public because of some restrictions.

Comment: I am able to access when I run an apache httpd server without an issue. I am trying to run projector on port 9999 which doesn't work https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-installer

Comment: Did you try _temporarily_ changing your security group to allow access from `0.0.0.0/0`? This will help determine whether you had the right or wrong IP address for your computer.

Comment: yes I did try with `0.0.0.0/0`. It didn't work. I used ssh tunneling instead which worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I have opened all ports on my security group aws seems to be allowing me to only access the common ports like `22`, `80` and so on.

The only way I could finally access my remote server on port 9999 was by ssh tunneling:

```
ssh -TNL 9999:127.0.0.1:9999 <user>@<ip-address>
```